# Storing returned values of a function as structure array in C

Tags: c, structure

I have a function that prints out 11 points of a quadratic function ax^2 + bx + c with a, b, c as input. The function works fine except I need to use structures, not just variables x and y. How can I get my function to return a structure value and store it in a structure array then print out the structure array?

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct point *findpoint(int a, int b, int c){
  int i, x, y;
  x = -5;
  for  (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
  {
    y = (a * (x * x)+ (b * x) + c);
    printf("The points are {%d, %d}\n", x, y);
    x++;   
  } 
}

struct point arr_point[11];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

struct point *ptr;
  printf("Enter coefficients a, b, c:");
  int a, b, c;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < argc; i++){
    scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
  }
  printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);

  findpoint(a, b, c);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want (a) the `main` routine to create an array of structures, the `findpoint` routine to return one structure per call, and the `main` routine to store that structure in its array, (b) the `main` routine to create an array of structures and the `findpoint` routine to directly store values in one element of that structure per call, (c) the `main` routine to create an array of structures and the `findpoint` routine to store values in all of those structures in one call, (d) the `findpoint` routine to create an array of structures and return it, filled in, or (e) something else?

Comment: I'm trying to do the first option (a) where main stores the the structure and prints it

Comment: Okay, then the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727162/298225) shows one way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias for your struct with `typedef`:

```
typedef struct {
  int x;
  int y;
} Foo_t;

Foo_t returnStruct() {
    Foo_t foo = {1,2};
    return foo;
}

int main() {
  const uint8_t SIZE_ARRAY = 2;
  Foo_t arrayFoo[SIZE_ARRAY];

  arrayFoo[0] = returnStruct();
  arrayFoo[1] = returnStruct();
  for(uint8_t i=0;i<SIZE_ARRAY;i++) {
    printf("Index %d: x=%d y=%d \n", i, arrayFoo[i].x, arrayFoo[i].y);
  }
    
}
```

Comment: @DavidCullen Return a pointer to a local variable and return a struct are different things